# Scroll to an element given in the location hash, when said element is loaded asynchronously on page load

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

I am passing an element ID using the location hash like so:

```
https://example.com/object/id#sub-object
```

However, the list of `sub-object` elements is loaded dynamically from an api after page load.

How can I scroll the viewport to the given element once the async request completes? Given that it's location is not available in the DOM on page load.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself, I used jquery for the scroll animation because, easy.

```
if(window.location.hash && !this.hasScrolled){

    var hash = location.hash.substring(1);

    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: this.$refs[hash][0].offsetTop -200} ,800);

    this.hasScrolled = true;
 }
```

This had to happen in the `updated()` hook on the component as this is the point when the element's offset is known. I added a `hasScrolled` property  (initially set to `false`) so I can make sure it only does the scroll on initial page load.